# restore previous assembly value?

Tags: assembly, x86

i want to see what the previous value of EAX is and to do that i'm using `POP EAX` but then when i try to restore it by using popad its not restoring its value it was BEFORE i used `POP EAX`

```
PUSHAD
POP EAX <-- Now i see the value i wanted to see to compare the new EAX
CMP EAX, 1
JE JMP_TO_SOME_CODE

//DO STUFF

POPAD <-- I want to restore eax back to what it was BEFORE i used POP EAX
RET
```

but when i do the above it dosen't restore it back to EAX original value, how can i do this in assembly?

Comment: Since you are new, I will not downvote you, but I _strongly_ recommend reading some tutorials about assembly (you will find good recommendations here). Asking questions like this won`t get you very far - even if you get a meaningful answer, it will not solve the programming problem you are facing. Better would be describing what you are trying to do (this part is missing in the question), and not only what you have tried, because what you have tried is most likely based on wrong assumptions and lack of understanding.

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing doesn't really make any sense. The next type of pop instruction immediately after a `PUSHAD` must be a `POPAD` in order for the stack to not become corrupted (unless you execute the same amount of individual `POP`s to restore the stack pointer as `POPAD` would).

`PUSHAD` pushes all the general purpose registers onto the stack, having a single `POP` afterwards is going to pull off some random register's value off of the stack and have the stack pointer pointing in an invalid spot for a `POPAD` to be executed.

- `EAX` doesn't lose its value after having it pushed onto the stack.
- `POP EAX` doesn't magically fill `EAX` with a previous value.

If you want to compare `EAX` to a previous value then you're going to need to store it's value in another register or as a "local" variable on the stack.

Comment: I'm quite new to assembly, therefore i'm not understanding your answer much, how do i set a local varable on the stack? how is that done?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't use assembly in a while, but I think I'm right in saying that there is only one stack involved here and so POP is removing one of the values pushed onto the stack by PUSHAD and so when you use POPAD all the values you originally pushed using PUSHAS would be in one of the other general purpose registers. If [this article](http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/pushad.htm) is correct then maybe your EAX is in ECX?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
PUSH  EAX
```

instedad

```
PUSHAD
```

The oposite instruction of PUSHAD is POPAD and store or restore 8 registers to/from stack.

You can use also 8 pop instruction to restore stack after PUSHAD.

```
    mov  eax, 123456
    pushad      //store 8 registers to stack: EAX, ECX, EDX, EBX, ESP, EBP, ESI, EDI
//
    pop  eax    //restore EDI
    pop  eax    //restore ESI
    pop  eax    //restore EBP
    pop  eax    //restore ESP
    pop  eax    //restore EBX
    pop  eax    //restore EDX
    pop  eax    //restore ECX
    pop  eax    //restore EAX   now the eax register contain start value 123456
```